# Why didn't the Enterprise modulate its shield frequency?

Tags: star-trek, movie, star-trek-generations

In the movie *Star Trek: Generations*, when the Klingons stole their shield frequencies, why didn't they just modulate their shield frequency, just like against the Borg in "Q Who".

I have been giving this some thought and can't figure it out. Did I miss something?

Comment: Off the top of my head, poor writing and/or poor procedure on the part of the Federation. You'd think that the computer would be programmed to automatically cycle the frequency when any structural damage was detected without an attendant collapse of a segment of the shield, but apparently not.  Could be bad for anyone in transporter transit.. but still -  So could damage to the ship.

Comment: I know, poor writing and bad design. But couldn't they still manually change the frequency.

Comment: They could.. but that requires them to realize what's going on first.  (Yeah; I know.  It should be a default action based on what we've seen.. but they don't seem to have come to that conclusion.)  It looks like they are busy being baffled instead of instantly assuming their frequency had been compromised, as the Computer should.

Comment: For future reference, questions that have the format "What if _____ happened" are tricky to ask on this site. See the meta discussion [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/close-reasons-what-if-happened), but they're not always a good fit. I'm not saying this one's not a good fit (it's probably okay), just something to keep in mind in the future

Comment: Ultimately this answer will be opinion based.  I suggest @K-H-W post his opinion as the answer as it's as good as it's going to get as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @K-H-W I believe the Borg  battles are the only prior occasions where their shields have been penetrated without being destroyed first. Not immediately realizing that the Klingons have the shield frequency is understandable, but it would have to be a case of pure incompetence for them to suddenly forget the only known (and standard, for that matter) counter-measure to their shields being bypassed. It should have immediately jumped to mind as something to try simply because of the similarity. The Enterprise crew is too often portrayed as extremely competent for that to make much sense.

Comment: @jpmc26 -- Exactly; there should be a number of predefined scenarios that either they (or the computer) automatically respond to.  The ship being struck despite the shields being fully operation is one.  Do they know it's compromised?  **No**.  But is changing the frequency a quick, simple counter measure to a number of possible causes?  **Yes**.  Ah, well - perhaps there's some logical, but never stated, reason, like the shields go down for a second when the frequency is changed.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the shield frequency was stolen by remote transmission via Geordi hacked visor. Even if the frequency was changed, it wouldn't have helped. Geordi would be keeping track of it.

Comment: @cde  I never thought of that

Comment: @cde But Riker didn't know that, he should have tried anyway.

Comment: [You're not the only one to have problems with that battle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azSh47-oRPI#t=1m39.5s).

Comment: @cde Unless I'm mistaken, the standard response to the Borg was to *randomize* the frequency *continually*. It would probably be changing too fast for Geordi to keep up, much less the Klingons watching.

Comment: I've just rewatched the scene where the Klingons obtain the number. The wording is interesting, and I'm wondering if they might shed some light on the issue: "Their shields are operating on a **modulation** of 257.4" (emphasis mine). So... maybe the shields were already on a varying frequency, but not randomly? And this number allowed the Klingons to predict how it would change? This is all technobable, anyway.

Answer (score 7):

No, you didn't miss anything.

Out of universe: It's terrible writing.

In universe: I reckon the Enterprise bridge crew panicked.

All of the command crew on the Enterprise bridge had faced the Borg.  One of them should have noticed the similarity of the situation and suggested rotating shield frequencies.

[It gets worse the more you think about it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azSh47-oRPI#t=1m39.5s)

Why isn't rotating shield frequencies on shield penetration standard procedure?  Why wait to be penetrated?  Why not have the computer change your shield frequencies periodically in battle automatically?  I don't recall any discussion of a downside of rotating frequencies.  If there's a legit transport in progress through the shields, the computer knows to wait.

Why was one of the most important numbers on a starship being prominently displayed on a screen anyone can walk past and glance at?  The Federation are a bunch of trusting dupes who don't put locks on things, but come on!

Why didn't Riker order Worf to disable their weapons?  Shields or no shields, the Enterprise-D should have been able to kick the snot out of a [second-hand D12 Bird Of Prey that had been retired 20 years before](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Klingon_Bird-of-Prey#Designations).  I don't recall mention of the Enterprise's weapons being offline (and I'm not rewatching it to check).

In the comments people have mentioned maybe shield frequency rotation hadn't become a thing yet.  [Voyager rotates shield frequencies all the time](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Shield_frequency).  USS Voyager left the Alpha Quadrant, and thus contact with the Federation, in 2371 the same year as [Generations](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations) takes place.  The Voyager crew never faced the Borg, but they knew to rotate shield frequencies when their shields were being mysteriously penetrated.

The original Enterprise faced a similar situation in Wrath of Khan, an enemy catches them with their shields down, but even worse because Reliant was an even match for the Enterprise.  That turned into a tense, exciting, intelligent space battle where every shot counts.  Remembering that just makes the Generations battle even worse.

Comment: To be fair, the Voyager is a newer, post Borg contact ship. It has Borg tactics in mind, like the defiant. Notice the Enterprise E was a better match to Borg ships than the D.

Comment: @cde How does the ship change the bridge crew's basic tactics?

Comment: The ease of which re modulating the shields can be done? And the phasers and torpedoes would need matching modulation changes. Even the phaser rifles and hand phasers need tinkering with to have them rotate modulation. New ship, new tech, new tactics

Comment: @cde I see where you're going.  I find it hard to believe that the flagship of the Federation, and the only Federation ship which has faced the Borg multiple times, didn't get upgrades to change their shield frequencies quickly.  Shelby has Data change their weapon frequencies on the fly in Best Of Both Worlds years earlier.  I'll have to go back and see if they're equally casual about shield frequencies.  They wouldn't even have to "keep them guessing", Lursa and B'Etor aren't the Borg, they could have just had to change it once.

Comment: "In universe: I reckon the Enterprise bridge crew panicked." - I accept your "Out of universe" answer but not this - look at how quickly they came up with the idea to force the klingon ship to cloak (disabling *their* shields) which was a lot more complex...

Answer (score 3):

No reason is given in the script or the novelisations however we can make an in-universe guess; the two people who have ready access to the shield systems (Worf at Tactical and Data at the Science station) are both occupied and while Riker could order them to spend their time sorting out their defenses, he favours tackling the problem head on and destroying the Klingons;

> "Deanna!" Riker shouted. "Take the helm. Get us out of orbit!" Troi
>   propelled herself from her chair and raced un- steadily across the
>   rocking deck to the helm. Within seconds, Veridian III disappeared
>   from the viewscreen --but the Klingon vessel was in full pursuit. Not
>   enough, Riker knew, as he squinted his eyes at the dazzling glow of
>   another approaching torpedo. Lursa and B'Etor had found a way to
>   outwit the Enterprise's superior firepower; it was time for Riker to
>   return the favor.
>
> ...
>
> "As their cloak begins to engage, their shields will drop." "Right,"
>   Riker said. "And they'll be vulnerable for at least two seconds." He
>   glanced at the android. **"Data, lock on to that plasma coil." "No
>   problem," Data answered, confident. He hurried over to a bulkhead,
>   removed a panel, and began rerouting circuitry at inhuman speed**.
>
> ...
>
> **"Worf." Riker turned to the Klingon. "Prepare a spread of photon
>   torpedoes. We'll have to hit them the instant they begin to cloak."**
>   "Aye, sir." Worf began to work his console.
>   <sub>[Star Trek - Generations Official Novelisation](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations_%28novel%29)</sub>

---

It's also theoretically possible that the Enterprise *was* rotating frequencies but that since the Klingons still had a live feed to Geordi's VISOR (and since he would certainly have been monitoring the shield during a battle) that they were simply using the same trick to change their torpedo frequencies each time they remodulated the shields.